# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined when using bundleconfig in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRcM8.png)>

> jQuery v1.8.3
>
> jQuery UI - v1.12.1

I have included jquery librraries from scripts folder in bundleconfig.

Bundleconfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/simplePagination.js",
          "~/Scripts/validation.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebScript.js"));
```

In the console window there are below two errors reported. how to fix it

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (WebScript.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.A (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Check that there are definitely no other `<script>` tags other than your bundle.  The error message `at jquery-ui.min.js` does not match up with a "bundle" which will be a single js file.

Comment: In layout file this bundles are refered. no places script tag is found: @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")

Comment: Found a solution, remove min from all scripts and css and bundleconfig. it worked

Answer (score 0):

There are Some more steps to complete the script rendering by using the bundle config.

Please Register the bundle config in the Application_Start Method that exists in the "global.asax.cs"

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Then Render script bundle in the header section of the Application by using the name which is declared in the bundle config.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jquery/Script");
```

The specified Error message will show in the console when the script files not rendering properly.

You can see the script files which are rendering correct using the "View page source" option ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> )

Comment: Yes all the steps were followed. What worked is to remove min from scripts and css

Comment: Yes, this issue exist in MVC 4, it can be ignoring  by edit the mvc ignore list for bundle config, and this has been fixed in MVC 5 for min files. its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, remove min from all scripts and css and bundleconfig. it worked